# MVC 3 - multiple controllers or controller with multiple actions plus routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm putting together a simple enough brochure site and decided to use MVC3 as a learning opportunity. Content of certain sections of the website will be stored in a DB and can be updated by an admin via a simple GUI. I decided not to use a prebuilt CMS again to learn how to do database operations in this language which is new to me.

I want a very simple URL structure:

```
foo.com (home)
foo.com/bio
foo.com/news
foo.com/about
foo.com/events
```

etc

The straightforward way to achieve that is to have a controller for each page, and use the `Index()` ActionResult of each controller.

Is it OK / best practice to have a controller for each of these pages of the site? News and Events won't have subpages, but might have paging, with the URL looking something like

```
foo.com/news/
foo.com/news/page2
foo.com/news/page3
foo.com/news/page4
```

If I had a single controller, and used multiple actions, the URLs by default look like

```
foo.com (home)
foo.com/home/bio
foo.com/home/news
foo.com/home/about
foo.com/home/events
```

Which would then have me updating the routing to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the use of controllers, I think the best practice is to have a particular controller for a domain of action or domain of content, not by the hierarchy of your main menu.

For example:

Your main page:

```
foo.com
```

Controller -> Home

Method -> Index

Parameter -> null

```
foo.com/news/2
```

Controller -> news

Method -> Index

Parameter -> 2

But Home and News are two different "equal" controllers, it just happens that the first controller the user interacts with is the Home controller.

Comment: Doesn't particularly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to use a single controller, you might try,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{page}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { page = new PagingConstraint() }
);
```

as route defination. And to only allow paging for "news" and "events", use a custom route constraint as,

```
public class PagingConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly string[] PagingEnabledActions = new string[] { "news", "events" };

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[parameterName].ToString()) || new Regex(@"^[Pp][Aa][Gg][Ee][0-9]+$", RegexOptions.Compiled).IsMatch(values[parameterName].ToString())
            && PagingEnabledActions.Contains(values["action"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.